# Python: Caesar Cipher

Tags: python

Hello everyone I am new to python and I am writing a program called cipher.py that asks the user for a string and a shift amount and then display the the ciphered string. I  wonder why I got 'function' object is not iterate errors. I got errors in line 19 and 36 saying 'function' object is not iterate.

Here is my code:

```
def Ciphertext():
    print('Please enter a string to be ciphered:', end='')
    Ciphertext = input()
    return input()

def Character():
    while True:
        Character = 0
        print('Please enter a shift amount between 0 and 25:', end='')
        Character = (input())
        Max_Character = 26
        if (float(Character) <= 26):
             if (float(Character) > 1):
              print(Character)
              break


def getShiftedcipher(Ciphertext, Character):
    for Character in Ciphertext:
        if Character.isalpha():
            var = ord(Character)
            var += Ciphertext
        if Character.islower():
            if var < ord('a'):
            var += 26
        if Character.isupper():
            if var < ord('A'):
            var += 26
    else:
         print('Please enter a shift amount between 0 and 25:', end='')
         return 

   print(getShiftedcipher(Ciphertext, Character))
```

Here are my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\cipher.py", line 36, in <module>
print(getShiftedcipher(Ciphertext, Character))
File 
"C:\Users\ALIENWARE\Desktop\cipher.py", line 19, in getShiftedcipher
for Character in Ciphertext:
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please don't describe your error in vague terms, copy and paste the whole exception and traceback into your question.

Comment: i will i am working on it

Comment: I fixed all or most of the errors you suggested??? I don't understand why I got something like 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

Comment: If you want to ask a followup question, create a new question, don't try to edit your existing one into asking something different.

Comment: But from a quick glance: It looks like you've added a `return` with no value to the end of `Ciphertext`, so it always returns `None`, rather than the string you got from `input`. I don't know why you did that, but that's the cause of at least this problem: you can't iterate over `None`, because it makes no sense.

Comment: I changed couple minutes ago and it doesn't work. Still got the same error.

Comment: Well, you probably have another problem. If you don't know how to debug that other problem, create a new question, and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow is no good for remotely iteratively debugging other people's code; it only works for asking a specific question that likely has a specific answer. There might be another site that can help you. (CodeReview is going for "what seems wrong in my program", but only once you've got it working; I don't know what's good for where you're at.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
print(getShiftedcipher(Ciphertext, Character))
```

The `getShiftedcipher` function that you wrote expects to get a string or other iterable for its first argument. But you're passing it a function, `Ciphertext`, not a string. So, when it tries to use that function as a string, you get an error.

You're also passing another function, `Character`, for the second argument. You get away with this, because `getShiftedcipher` just ignores its second argument.

Presumably what you wanted to do is *call* the `Ciphertext` function, and pass the *result*, rather than the function itself. Like this:

```
print(getShiftedcipher(Ciphertext(), Character()))
```

---

You've got a lot of other problems in your code beyond this one. Off the top of my head:

- `Ciphertext` calls `input` twice, ignoring the first input from the user and waiting for another one, which will be at least very confusing.
- `Character` doesn't actually return a value, it just prints one out and then `return`s nothing, so whenever you call `Character()`, you're just going to get `None`. You need to `return float(Character)`.
- You really shouldn't use `float` when you want an integer between 0 and 25; use `int`.
- Your prompts ask for a number between 0 and 25, but your code checks for a number between 1 and 26.
- In `getShfitedCipher`, you take a number in the parameter `Character`, but then you immediately hide that by creating another variable with the same name in `for Character in Ciphertext:`. Use two different names. Maybe call the parameter `Shift`.
- In `getShiftedCipher`, you're doing `var += Ciphertext`. But `Ciphertext` isn't a number that you can add like that, it's a string. You probably wanted `var += Shift` (assuming the previous change).
- You do all that work to compute a new value in `var` for each character… but then you never do anything with it. Probably you want to `print(chr(var), end='')` or something.
- You try to handle "rollover" by checking if the new value has become `<` the letter `A` (or `<` the letter `a`). But that's never going to happen, because you're adding positive numbers, not subtracting. The actual problem is if the new value is `>` the letter `Z`, in which case you need to subtract 26.
- Your `for…else` loop in `getShiftedCipher` doesn't make any sense. An `else` in a `for` loop gets run whenever you exit the loop without a `break`. You don't want it to re-print the `Character` prompt here, so why is there code that does that?
- You really should pick a consistent style for your names. It helps avoid this kind of confusion, and makes your code easier to read. Also, don't throw in extra unnecessary parentheses; just do `if float(Character) <= 26:`. See [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more on this.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you are trying to iterate over a function.

```
for Character in Ciphertext:
```

Ciphertext is a reference to a function here, not a string like you probably assume